# CSS style added to dynamically generated ordered list row

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've inherited an issue that I'm having a great amount of difficulty solving.

We're dynamically creating new ordered list rows from data entered into an unordered list row. The user enters some data into the `<ul>` and then we populate it with information based on the entered data. We then `remove()` the row from the `<ul>` and then add it to the `<ol>` with `appendTo()`.

After creating the new `<ol>` item, the row gains a `style="width: 100%;"` tag that really screws up
the formatting of a KendoUI datepicker in the row.

If we save the data on the page and refresh/reload the page, the formatting is back to normal with no `width` tag on any of the added rows.

I've resolved the problem myself by calling `removeAttr('style')` on the element, but this feels "hackish" to me and I'd really like to know how to find what's adding the style to the newly added row and fix that.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you dynamically creating? How is it being saved on refresh? Whats your code like? What have you tried? etc...

Comment: The row gains style 100% which messes up the formatting. Seems you allready found your problem. ^^

Comment: it doesn't just gain `style="width: 100%;"`... Figure out where that's coming from.

Comment: @somethinghere We're creating the row by assigning a reference to the `<ul>` row in the `$( document ).ready()` function. This row is populated with the data the user enters and is then removed from the DOM and and then added to the `<ol>` using `appendTo()`.

Comment: @slicedToad Right, I understand that it doesn't just gain the syle. The issue is that there are multiple possible sources of the style from various CSS stylesheets (some of which are 3rd party and minified). I was just hoping someone had an idea of how I could narrow down where the declaration might be coming from, if that's the issue.

Comment: @Electric_Wizard If the css is a style attribute directly in the html, it was added by JS, not a css file. Post the HTML for that row when it is in it's problem state.

Comment: @Electric_Wizard - Kendo is notorious for adding `style="width: 100%"` on dynamically added elements.  I'd highly recommend writing some transformative CSS files to override this behavior, as anything you do to their CSS/JS is likely to be overridden the next time the company updates.  Telerik is a crap-fest, and unfortunately there won't be a nice clean solution to this problem.  So glad I don't have to work with it anymore.

Comment: @JoshBurgess Thanks so much for verifying this. I'm glad I'm not crazy. Now to figure out how to override this behavior, as you suggested...

Comment: I'll put it in an answer, very easy to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `transform.kendo-ui.css` file or something similar.

You can then put in that file, with the specificity as you need it (forgive me for the guesses at class names, it's been about 10 months since I last had to work on Kendo):

```
.k-list-container > .k-list-item,
.k-animation-container .k-list-item,
etc. etc. {
   width:auto!important;
}
```